# Two Forms open and their state changed

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on an MDI Application. In that I open a Form maximized. Out of this form (using a button) I open a new form, both form open in a MDI form.

This 2nd form is set to `WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;`. AND first form is set to `WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;`

Then BOTH Forms are turned into normal, which I really don´t want them to do. The 1st form should remain maximized and the other should open in normal state. I don´t want to do it like "use the resize-event of the first form" - that´s no solution, because my users could like to really resize that form...

This is how I open 2nd form:

```
 Form26SeperateEntry chilform = new Form26SeperateEntry();
  chilform.MdiParent = this;
  chilform.Location = new Point(700, 30);
  chilform.Show();
  chilform.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

Any ideas on how to manage this?

Comment: That's just not possible in MDI, only one child can be maximized and it must be the active one.  Any other children are always underneath it.  Lots of docking layout libraries out there that provide an alternative to MDI.

Comment: or maybe just not make the second form an mdi child, if it's possible for you.

Answer (score 0):

set MDI Child form Property

```
AutoSize= false;
AutoSizeMode= GrowOnly;
```